# How to get the joint acceleration in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gz-sim

I'm quite new to Gazebo and I'm trying to access the kinematic properties of a joint during simulation on my custom plugin. While in the official documentation there's a Joint class exposing methods to get [position](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1Joint.html#ac144bae2833c73f0b7d3033b33ae1e80) and [velocity](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1Joint.html#a5361ab6e51b0b347da16a5b69e8192d8), I've not found a similar method for the acceleration. Is it something I can get through the ECM?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to calculate that yourself. Since Gazebo already provides a method of getting velocity, all you need to do is get the derivative of this to get the acceleration:
$$
a = \frac{v_t - v_{t-1}}{t_t - t_{t-1}}
$$
You just have to store the previous velocity value in the previous iteration.